# Is there an english word that means opposite yet complementary and orthogonal without a positive/negative connotation?

Tags: terminology, programming

I am looking for a word to use to describe technical traits of a programming language that are the opposite of each other yet complementary.

There is no positive or negative connotation to either trait. Similar to the concept of *yin and yang*.

For example “deserialization” is the opposite of “serialization” in that they are *reciprocal* behaviors to each other but also *orthogonal* as well, as in the computer science jargon that there is a fixed minimal set of instructions to do either thing.

#### I am looking for a word to describe the concept of this relationship and that this is the only way to do the *thing* that is being described.

Comment: Any particular reason why *complementary* wouldn't do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inverse** Operations and Functions article on [Massey University](http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/InvFun/InvOp.htm) website

> The operations put on and take off undo each other. If we do one
>   operation then the other, we end up where we started. Put on is the
>   **inverse** operation to take off.  Take off is the inverse operation of
>   put on.  Such operations form an operation-inverse operation pair.
>
> The same is true in mathematics.  Most operations have an inverse
>   operation.

Comment: this seems like a good word for me to use right now, it does not convey that this is the single way to do something but I will keep searching

Answer (score 4):

There can be no such word, because it would make no sense.  *Opposite* means along the same dimension yet going the other way along that dimension.  *Complementary* and *orthogonal* mean along different dimensions.

Comment: in computer science `orthogonal` means the smallest set if unique operations available without redundancy.

Comment: That comes originally from a geometric analysis using the sense Greg pointed out. Special senses of standard terms abound in special contexts, but are not generally understood outside that context. This is ELU, not stack overflow.